# how to set result date wise

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has below records, and what I need is set below results into datatable date wise.

```
date        code      lc_code      qty
7/1/2018    MC20651    1126         322.00
6/1/2018    MC10102    3356         30.00
5/1/2018    MC10201    4422         56.00
7/1/2018    MC10303    5065         55.00
4/1/2018    MC20902    7012         65.00
4/1/2018    MC50201    1258         45.00
3/1/2018    MC10201    1126         86.00
3/1/2018    MC50201    7012         14.25
2/1/2018    MC20651    1258         322.00
7/1/2018    MC20651    3356         78.00
```

Here  below is what I need to set to datatable. Can you provide the best query to do that?,i manage to get sum of these value but i struggle to get that value in row wise

---

```
|  Code     |   2/1/2018 |  3/1/2018  |   4/1/2018 |    5/1/2018   |  6/1/2018  |    7/1/2018   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC20651  |  322.00|   78.00|   0.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 | 322.00 |        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10102  |   0.00 |  30.00 |   0.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 |   0.00 |        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10201  |   86.00|   0.00 |  56.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 | 134.25 |        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10303  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |  55.00  |   0.00 |   0.00 |        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC20902  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 | 960.00  |  65.00 |   0.00 |        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC50201  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00  |  14.25 |   45.00|        0.00|           0.00|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You are lookinig at PIVOT but do you have predefined list of date column to be pivoted.

Comment: If your date list not predefined, you are looking at Dynamic PIVOT, which can't be achieved with plain SQL query and you will have to use procedure to do that returning desired resultset.

Comment: What's a datatable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN` With `SUM` function to make it.

```
SELECT code,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `2/1/2018`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '3/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `3/1/2018`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '4/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `4/1/2018`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '5/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `5/1/2018`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '6/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `6/1/2018`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '7/1/2018' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `7/1/2018`
FROM T
GROUP BY code
```

**Edit**

if you don't want to hard code you can use  `Dynamic PIVOT`

Dynamic created your SQL, then use excute it.

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

look like this.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN date = ''',
      date,
      '''THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      date,'`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM T;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT code,', @sql, ' 
                   FROM T
                   GROUP BY code;');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://rextester.com/RRPOD72484)

Comment: can't hardcode the date,i need get values without hardcoding

Comment: @Kasun if you don't want to hardcode you can use  `Dynamic PIVOT`, I edit my answer.